# A log which holds all actions

Tags: logs

I was wondering if Centos 6.4 has some kind of log which stores most actions that happen.

The issue is as following. I have two VirtualMachines, both running CentOS and on both independant machines (tough on the same physical machine), there are files being removed. I have no idea who or what removes those files, we Bacula running but i don't want to point fingers, tough that is the only external source which really handles / does something with files.

So my question is if there is a place i could look to see what is going on. I just had this issue happen again on me 30 minutes ago, quite some folders got removed, and quite some files (even config files for some web apps).

Comment: You could log the `unlink`, `rmdir` and `rename` system calls with the audit system (`auditctl`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ok, i will look in that that, thank you. But at this point there is nothing i can look in to to see what could have happend?